# Ambiguous method call with JvmSynthetic setter

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I have a class with `@JvmSynthetic` setters in order to provide only fluent builder-like setters for Java clients:

```
class PersonBuilder {
    @set:JvmSynthetic    // hide a void setter from Java
    var age: Int? = null

    @set:JvmSynthetic
    var name: String? = null

    fun setAge(age: Int?) = apply { this.age = age }

    fun setName(name: String?) = apply { this.name = name }

    fun build() = Person(age!!, name!!)
}
```

And call it like this on the Java side:

```
new PersonBuilder()
        .setAge(22)  // <- "error"
        .setName("Peter")
        .build();
```

It does compile & run, but Android Studio shows the error "*Ambiguous method call. Both setAge (Integer) in PersonBuilder and setAge (Integer) in PersonBuilder match*" and doesn't provide any auto-suggestions and code formating after this "error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no need to use the `@set:JvmSynthetic` notation, just changing the visibility of variables should do the trick. Try this:

```
class PersonBuilder {
    private var age: Int? = null
    private var name: String? = null

    fun setAge(age: Int) = apply { this.age = age }

    fun setName(name: String) = apply { this.name = name }

    fun build() = Person(age!!, name!!) //be careful!
}
```

Anyway, be careful with the build function. There are no guarantees that the functions setAge and setName will be called before it, so you can get a NullPointerException

## Update

Another way to solve this problem by keeping `@JvmSynthetic` is to add the `@JvmField` notation as well. See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-jvm-synthetic) for more information.

Comment: I need `@set:JvmSynthetic` to use those setters at the Kotlin side

Comment: See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-jvm-synthetic). Section 3 says: " _Note that if we have a Kotlin field annotated with *@JvmSynthetic* but not annotated with *@JvmField*, then the generated getter and setter are not considered synthetic methods and can be accessed just fine_ "

Comment: *@JvmField* solves the problem. @bruno-azevedo can you please write the complete answer so I can mark the question solved?